# Inherit from a Custom Operator in Airflow

Tags: python, inheritance, airflow

I am trying to create a CustomBaseOperator that inherits from the Airflow BaseOperator. The CustomBaseOperator works fine, but when I try to create a ChildOperator that inherits from the CustomBaseOperator, Airflow treats it as a CustomBaseOperator.

The CustomBaseOperator has an execute function that looks like this :

```
def make_request(self): 
    print("Parent request")

def execute(self, context): 

    self.make_request()
```

In the Child Operator, I redefine make_request:

```
class ChildOperator(CustomBaseOperator): 
    
    @apply_defaults
    

    def make_request(self): 
        print("Child Request")
```

Whenever I run a task that uses ChildOperator, it prints "Parent request" and the legends shows it as a CustomBaseOperator ...
My operators are in an "operators" folder in the "plugins" folder. I am guessing that I can only inherit from "official" operators when creating a custom operator in that folder.
Do you know how I could make the inheritance work ?

Comment: Please show the full classes code. both CustomBaseOperator and ChildOperator. What you wrote should works so something else is going on

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator


class CustomBaseOperator(BaseOperator):
    def make_request(self):
        print("Parent request")

    def execute(self, context):
        self.make_request()


class ChildOperator(CustomBaseOperator):
    def make_request(self):
        print("Child Request")


with DAG(dag_id="test_dag", start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    test = ChildOperator(task_id="test")
```

This will print `Child Request` and display `ChildOperator` in the Airflow UI. Also, note that setting `@apply_defaults` is deprecated since Airflow 2.0, it is now applied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue : I was using a function that loops into locals() to set self.param = param for every param.

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the specific code iterating over locals() that was causing the error you described?

Comment: Yes, it was this function : 
`def auto_self_params(args: dict):
    """Sets automatically the parameters in __init__ class with locals() on argument"""
    theobj = args.pop("self", None)
    for key, val in args.items():
        setattr(theobj, key, val)
`